# how to parse json string in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, json, httpresponse

I'm new to Android. I know a little about JSON parsing in Android. I'm parsing a twitter feed where I want to parse the tag called "user", which contains `profile_image_url` and `screen_name`.

The JSON feed is [here](https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=@Samanthaprabhu2&count=50). Here is my code:

```
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

// getting JSON string from URL
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

try {
    // Getting Array of Contacts

    contacts = json.getJSONArray(USER);

    // looping through All Contacts
    for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) in android.

```
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    String jsonString = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url).tostring();

    JSONArray json= new JSONArray(jsonString);



    try {

        // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){
              JSONObject contacts = json.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONObject user = contacts.getJSONObject("user");

                String imageUrl = user.getString("profile_image_url");
                String screenName = user.getString("Screen_name");

            }
        }catch(Exception e)
   {
   }
```

Comment: wat i want is pretty simple..in the above json url there is a tag named "user" where i want to parse those tages "profile_image_url" and screen "Screen_name"....i m coming from a ios background where i parse using NSDictionary..could u give me an example to parse those two tags

Comment: sorry but could u explain me how to parse the tag "user" and run it in for loop..the above code that i have written is totally messed up

Comment: In this feed you have a JSONArray() and that array has JSONObject of user. Let me add it in answer.

Comment: could u make it little detailed like from parsing the url..will be so greatful

Comment: does jparser provide any method like getJSONArrayFromUrl() ?

Comment: i m getting an error in JSONElement..is that an inbuilt class

Comment: could u tell me how to store that in an array..i no its too much to ask

Comment: i have parsed image url and i m gettin the image url .what i want is to store it in string array

Comment: ArrayList<String> imagesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
imagesArray.add(url);
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: i used the above it worked ..but i need the urls in String[];is it possbile

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `json.org` libraries which allow to work easily with JSON files, which is included in Android..

Yet you can use `Gson from Google, or Jackson` to do this....

**See this site its very helpful :**

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html

This above site also explains the twitter Json parsing..

**Eg:**

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    jsonObject.getString("name");
```

Comment: @DuseanSingh I think u did't saw the last 2 lines..where i showed a small snippet of code to tell him how to do it... and the site which i have marked as important has good examples in it......

Answer (score 1):

Use `Gson`. Check [user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide).

Example Model:

```
Class User
{
   public String profile_image_url;
   public String screen_name;
}
```

Example Parser:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
User user = gson.fromJson("['profile_image_url':'the_url', 'screen_name':'the_name']", User.class);
```

PS: make sure the name `profile_image_url` from json exactly same to the Class's member name.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code to get channel list from Youtube, I hope this helps

```
public void getYouTubeData(){
    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    URL url = null;
    urlString.append("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/CaliforniaDMV/playlists?v=2&alt=json");
    m_ytdata = new ArrayList<YoutubeChannelList.YouTubePlayListData>();

    try {
        url = new URL(urlString.toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    } catch (ProtocolException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    try {
        urlConnection.connect();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String result = null;
    if(inputStream != null){
     result = convertStreamToString(inputStream);
    } else {
        Log.d("NULLLL","NULL");
    }
    try {
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    urlConnection.disconnect();
    try {
        final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        final JSONObject jsonentry = json.getJSONObject("feed");
        int length = jsonentry.length();
        //final JSONObject jsonarr = jsonentry.getJSONObject("entry")
        final JSONArray jsonarr = jsonentry.getJSONArray("entry");
        int len = jsonarr.length();

        //Log.d("XXX", "Length is " + length + "arry len: " + len);

        for(int loop = 0;loop<len;loop++){
            YouTubePlayListData yt = new YouTubePlayListData();
            final JSONObject inner = jsonarr.getJSONObject(loop);
            yt.setIds(inner.getJSONObject("yt$playlistId").getString("$t"));
            //yt.setVideoId(getThumbnailImage(inner.getJSONObject("yt$playlistId").getString("$t")));
            yt.setUpdated(inner.getJSONObject("updated").getString("$t").substring(0,10));
            yt.setTitles(inner.getJSONObject("title").getString("$t"));
            yt.setCount(Integer.parseInt(inner.getJSONObject("yt$countHint").getString("$t")));
            //Log.d("LOOP","id: " +inner.getJSONObject("yt$playlistId").getString("$t"));
            //Log.d("LOOP","updated: " + inner.getJSONObject("updated").toString());
            //Log.d("LOOP","title: " + inner.getJSONObject("title").getString("$t"));
            m_ytdata.add(yt);
        }
        runOnUiThread(returnRes);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: wat i want is pretty simple..in the above json url there is a tag named "user" where i want to parse those tages "profile_image_url" and screen "Screen_name"....i m coming from a ios background where i parse using NSDictionary..could u give me an example to parse only those two tags

Comment: You can change the code to the tags that you want to pass, for example you can change following part yt.setIds(inner.getJSONObject("yt$playlistId").getString("$t"));
            //yt.setVideoId(getThumbnailImage(inner.getJSONObject("yt$playlistId").getString("$t")));
            yt.setUpdated(inner.getJSONObject("updated").getString("$t").substring(0,10));
            yt.setTitles(inner.getJSONObject("title").getString("$t"));

Answer (score 0):

vanilla JSON parser supplied with android can parse data, unfortunately
it builds full JSON model in memory (like DOM parser for XML )  - this works fine for
small data amounts,  but is not practicable  for slightly bigger data  as it allocates 
and hogs a lot of memory.

Some pull parser like  GSON  oder jackson would suit your task better (jackson claims to be faster, but also heavier jars and more dependencies - I prefer GSON)

You may also consider simple databinding library:

https://github.com/ko5tik/jsonserializer

( jars available from maven central )

With it parsing of JSON becomes looks this way:

https://github.com/ko5tik/accmeter/blob/master/src/main/java/de/pribluda/android/accmeter/file/SampleReader.java

( just provide java.io.Reader and class to fill fields in )